# Static assets not being served on Heroku/Thin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, thin

I'm having trouble with static assets (images and js and stylesheets) not being served on Heroku.
Works fine in my local dev env.

Errors look like this:

```
2011-08-08T02:58:45+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/stylesheets/reset.css" for 98.234.235.21 at 2011-08-07 19:58:45 -0700
2011-08-08T02:58:45+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-08-08T02:58:45+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/stylesheets/reset.css"):
```

I'm using:

- Ruby 1.9.2
- Rails 3.0.7
- Heroku with bamboo-mri-1.9.2 and thin webserver. (I followed default basic setup instructions on heroku.com)

I've searched on google / stackoverflow and tried the following with no luck:

- remove config.ru
- add `use ActionDispatch::Static, "#{Rails.root}/public"` to config.ru
- set `config.serve_static_assets = true` in staging.rb

Can anyone suggest a fix? Should I be using Cedar instead of Bamboo? Should I be using something else instead of thin?

Thanks!

---

**EDIT:**
js files are being served, but images and stylesheets are not.
I checked that the paths in my links are consistent.

`myapp.heroku.com/stylesheets/reset.css` - fails
`myapp.heroku.com/javascripts/jquery.js` - succeeds

I also attempted to set the following: `config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = nil`.
This goes along with `config.serve_static_assets = true` but noticed that Heroku forces these options no matter how you set them.  i.e. it does the following during startup:

```
-----> Detected Rails is not set to serve static_assets
       Installing rails3_serve_static_assets... done
-----> Configure Rails 3 to disable x-sendfile   
       Installing rails3_disable_x_sendfile... done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that the asset files didn't get pushed to heroku (I had a git screwup, not a heroku issue).

Heroku support pointed this out when I contacted them. They promptly replied with a detailed answer, which also included the following comments:

- Heroku gem is not required to run on Heroku
- Specify postgres gem in Gemfile; use postgres locally for development in place of sqlite3
- config.ru: Don't run the dispatcher directly, run the app container
- dont set x_sendfile_header to nil as this is not properly supported on Rails 3 (this is a Rails 3.1 setting)

Answer (score 0):

I am not confident that Heroku is running in the `staging` environment, I think it's running in the `production` environment instead and this is why your settings are not being applied.

Comment: Ryan, I configured it to run staging, and verified that my changes are being applied: `heroku config --remote staging` shows `RACK_ENV            => staging` and `RAILS_ENV           => staging`